# Нагрузка на сервер одного пользователя pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

Как Узнать на сколько нагружает сервер 1 пользователь телеграм бота?
Например: какую мощность сервера брать, для того чтобы могли 50 пользователей работать одновременно без всяких проблем?
Или приведите свои примеры ботов(опишите сколько одновременных пользователей могут пользоваться вашим ботом, укажите характеристики вашего сервера)
Например, сервер майнкрафт на одного пользователя выделяет 15мб памяти.

Comment: Вряд ли можно в отрыве от задачи дать оценку. Что делает Ваш бот? Он, например, может запускать рассчёт нейронки. А может отдавать текстовую строку. А как часто пользователи обращаются к боту? В простейшем случае, мне кажется, возьмите то, что Вам подходит по деньгам и не заморачивайтесь. А потом посмотрите.

Comment: Всё зависит от выполняемых функций и того, как это всё реализовано. Но по идее даже слабенького сервера хватит на обработку нескольких сотен юзеров. Например, количество оперативной памяти вообще не будет влиять на кол-во пользователей, если приложение однопоточное.